# Pros and Cons of Word vs Illustrator formatted resume

Tags: resume

I wondering what the pros and cons of submitting a Microsoft Word based resume vs submitting a resume that has been designed and laid out in something like Illustrator. Obviously the latter give much more flexibility in the aesthetics of the resume, while the former is a more utilitarian format. Any additional pros and cons I'm missing.

In looking at resumes as a hiring manager, seeing a well designed clean resume would definitely get my attention, particularly if the candidate was applying for a design or Ux position, but I'm applying for a more managerial position so I'm not sure how important it would be.

To be clear I would export the resume as a PDF so the text should be searchable.

Answer (score 1):

As you are not a designer/artist/clown etc and this isn't part of your portfolio.

Generally, a resume/CV has one main job: to get you an interview/job. 
When considering a candidate one of the questions any manager will be asking is "Will user379468 get work done or generate work for me?"
Word/PDF is standard and will be easy for them to deal with, anything 'specialist' is a pain and may well count against you.

You said you are looking at a managerial position, keep things simple and corporate. You don't want notepad but don't try to be too flashy. Let your skills and achievements be noticed, not your font.

Good luck!

Comment: I get you point, however it’s akin to a executive creative director roll, and I like to illustrate that I still have the capability to design ( which is something many CDs and above do not ) but again point taken.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if your resume as a designer should reflect your abilities. I thought that was what a portfolio was for?

In any case it might be a problem if you're going through recruitment agencies, as they invariably like to make minor changes before sending it over to a client (your potential new employer). They will usually strip off your contact details, to prevent being cut out the process and losing commission.

They mainly use Word for this, so illustrator or PDF formats won't be good, and they'll ask for Word anyway.